# How can I shrink QLabel images in a layout?

Tags: qt

I'm new to Qt, and I'm trying to make a 10x24 grid of some .png files. It seems like using a QGridLayout and filling it with QLabel objects is the best way to go, but the QLabels don't seem to automatically shrink to fit inside the available space, so I end up with this:

[image]

Also, I should mention I'm using a subclass of QLabel I created, and that the objects are created as part of an array in a container object:

```
void ObjectSlotArray::initialize() {
first = FIRST; 
isCreated = false;
layout = new QGridLayout(this);
for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
    array[c] = new ObjectSlot(c);
    layout->addWidget(array[c], (int)(c / 24), c % 24);
    array[c]->show();} }  //10x24 grid
```

Comment: General note: QGraphicsView stuff is traditionally used for views like you seem to have. Or, using Qt Quick 2 (QML) would be a more modern or Qt5-like approach. As long as you just have a grid of images, QWidgets should work, but as soon as you start wanting a lot of moving items, some graphical effects etc, your code starts to get messy fast.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. Most of the items in this app I'm making aren't gonna change position though, so hopefully I'll be alright.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
array[c]->setScaledContents(true);
```

Or in your ObjectSlot constructor:

```
setScaledContents(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

QLabel won't scale its image. You could add a resize event handler for your label class (or for the parent container) which would scale the images once the available space is known, then assign it to the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems to work:

```
void ObjectSlot::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    QPixmap* image = new QPixmap("://images/Box.png");
    setPixmap(image->scaled(width(),height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
    QLabel::paintEvent(event);}
```

Comment: This re-scales the image in *every* paint event. You should probably move the `setPixmap` to resize event instead. Alternatively, check if image needs to be re-scaled before doing it in paint event.